# android hidden php score

Tags: php, android, sql

I made an SQL database that with when I call this http://drymvizion.atwebpages.com/new_score.php?=pa&name=eleni&scor=23400 in explorer, it saves a high score in http://drymvizion.atwebpages.com/ that you can check it out.  I try to make a high score list in PHP. How can I call this in my android application without showing that in users? So they don't cheat and change numbers? The project is something casual so I don't care for a super protective solution, just something simple as I am not so experiment with SQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some hashing like `md5` (less popular may be better) to data your sent. And verify input data results in the same hash.

It won't be too hard to reverse-engineer, but at least users won't be able to send request just from the browser.

[SO: make in http request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android)